# PHP login script does not show error message, just goes to blank page

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm working on a login page. When I log in it works just fine. But when I test the error checking by leaving email and password fields blank, it does not show my error message, and naviagates to scripts/login.php which is just a blank page. The same issue happens with my forgot password script. if i do not enter an email, it navigates to scripts/forgot.php which is a blank page, but if if I enter an email, it still navigates to a blank page but the email with user info is sent correctly.

When I use include for both login.php and forgot.php, they work fine. Its only when I use the form action. 
Heres my code:

**login.php**

```
<?php include_once("../src/global.php");
$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];

//Error handling

    if((!$email) || (!$pass)){          
        $message = 'Please enter your email and/or password';
    }else{
    $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
    $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);

    if(isset($data[0]['Password'])) { 
        $contactPass = $data[0]['Password'];
        $id = $data[0]['Id'];
        $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
        $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);

        if ($contactPass !== $pass ){
            $message = 'The information you entered is incorrect';
        }else{
            //Start the session
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $contactPass;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

            if($remember == "yes"){
                //Create the cookies
                setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                setcookie("pass_cookie", $contactPass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
            }
            header("Location: ../home.php");
            }       
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**forgot.php**

```
<?php include_once("../src/global.php");
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];


        if((!$email)){
        $message = 'Please enter your email';
        }else{
    $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
    $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);
    if($email != $data[0]['Email']){
            $message = "There was an error processing your request. Please check that the email you entered is correct";
        }else{

        //Retrieve password
            $pass  =  $data[0]['Password'];
            //echo "your pass is ::".($pass)."";
            $to = $data[0]['Email'];
            $name = $data[0]['FirstName'];
            //echo "your email is ::".$email;
            //Details for sending E-mail
            $url = "http://caapitesting.com/";
            $body  = "Hi ".$name.",
            <br />
            <br />

            We're responding to a request you've made to retrieve your password to login to the Student Center.
            <br />
            <br />
            ------------------------------------
            <br />

            Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong> ".$to." </strong><br />
            Password&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong> ".$pass." </strong> 

            <br />  
            ------------------------------------
            <br />
            <br />

            <a href='".$url."'>Click here to sign in to the Student Center</a>

            <br /><br />

If you did not request your password, please contact us immediately by responding to this email.
<br /><br />
Sincerely,<br />
Client Attraction Support Team";
            $subject = "CABS Student Password Recovery";
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            // Additional headers
            $headers .= 'From: Client Attraction Support Team <students@clientattraction.com>' . "\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

                $message = "Your password has been emailed";    
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once("src/global.php");

if($logged == 1){
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit();
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="message"><?php print($message); ?></div>
<form action="scripts/login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" /><br>
<input id="option" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="Yes" checked="checked">
<label for="option"><span><span></span></span>Remember me</label>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="LOGIN" />
</form>



  <h6>Please enter your email</h6>

  <div class="message"><?php print($message); ?></div>

<form action="scripts/forgot.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>


</body>
```

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance

Joe

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: The way you are storing password is a security risk. Am assuming that you are not encrypting the passwords because you are sending the user a password. If you need help with that ask. People use the same password on more than one website. Don't be the one who exposes people's password. Do it for all of us if not your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a blank page because you're not redirecting or displaying anything if there was an error. So at the bottom add a redirect back to `index.php`. If the login was successful it won't hit this redirect, it will get the one that sends the user to `home.php`.

As for `$message`, you're setting that as a variable in the `login.php` file. `index.php` won't see this variable because it doesn't have access to it. Save it to a session variable, then in `index.php` you can set it to a local variable and unset the session variable.

I'm going to assume in `../src/global.php` you have `session_start()`. If you don't, you will need to include that in the top of each file.

**login.php**

```
<?php include_once("../src/global.php");
$_SESSION['message'] = "";

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];

    //Error handling

    if((!$email) || (!$pass)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Please enter your email and/or password';
    } else {
        $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
        $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);

        if(isset($data[0]['Password'])) {
            $contactPass = $data[0]['Password'];
            $id = $data[0]['Id'];
            $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
            $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);

            if ($contactPass !== $pass ) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'The information you entered is incorrect';
            } else {
                //Start the session
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $contactPass;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

                if($remember == "yes") {
                    //Create the cookies
                    setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                    setcookie("pass_cookie", $contactPass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                }
                header("Location: ../home.php");
            }       
        }
    }

    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once("src/global.php");

if($logged == 1){
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit();
}

$mesasge = $_SESSION['message'];
unset($_SESSION['message']);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="message"><?php print($message); ?></div>
<form action="scripts/login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" /><br>
<input id="option" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="Yes" checked="checked">
<label for="option"><span><span></span></span>Remember me</label>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="LOGIN" />
</form>



  <h6>Please enter your email</h6>

  <div class="message"><?php print($message); ?></div>

<form action="scripts/forgot.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>


</body>
```

Comment: you're my hero. Thanks! @slapyo

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the index page and let the form post to the index page by leaving the action empty `action=''`and just add the login script or the forgot script if the submit button is pressed. This way, I can re-use the entered email

I would change the submit name in the login part to `name="login"` and in the forgot part to `name="forgot"`

I would remove the session message from the other scripts and put it in the index script

**index.php**

```
if($logged == 1){
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit();// you don't need this, the header will redirect the page and won't reach here
}

// if the session message is set the put it in the message otherwise set the message to nothing
$message = isset($_SESSION['message']) ? SESSION['message'] : '';
unset($_SESSION['message']);

//include the forgot.php or login.php script here

If(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = "";
    include_once("scripts/login.php");
}elseif(isset($_POST['forgot'])){
    include_once("scripts/forgot .php");
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

 <div class="message"><?php print($message); ?></div>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" /><br>
<input id="option" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="Yes" checked="checked">
<label for="option"><span><span></span></span>Remember me</label>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN" />
</form>



  <h6>Please enter your email</h6>

  <div class="message"><?php print($message); ?></div>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="forgot " value="SUBMIT" />
</form>


</body>
```

You need to be storing encrypting passwords be fired storing them. Use the new built in php password hash function. All you to have do is be running php 5 or greater and use the default password_hash function like
 `$password_hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`
To store the password and in the login script use password_verify function like

```
$valid = password_verify($password, $contactPass);
```

The function returns true or false. 
In the login page,

**login.php**

```
<?

php include_once("../src/global.php");


    //use isset to check the form values and set them to null if not set
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? ($_POST['email'] : NULL;
    $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? ($_POST['pass'] : NULL;
    $remember = isset($_POST['remember']) ? ($_POST['remember '] : NULL ;

    //Error handling use empty

    if(is_null($email) || is_null($pass)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Please enter your email and/or password';
    } else {
        $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
        $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);

        if(isset($data[0]['Password'])) {
            $contactPass = $data[0]['Password'];
            $id = $data[0]['Id'];
            $returnFields = array('Id', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'Password');
            $data = $app->findByEmail($email, $returnFields);

                if(!password_verify($pass,contactPass) ) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'The information you entered is incorrect';
            } else {
                //Start the session
                //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                //$_SESSION['pass'] = $contactPass;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

                if($remember == "yes") {
                    //Create the cookies


         setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
                setcookie("pass_cookie", $contactPass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
            }
            header("Location: ../home.php");
        }       
    }
}
// Don't need to redirect
//header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```